# SpEL Memory Leak using mixed mode

Tags: spring-el

I'm having a problem using springs expression language when running in mixed mode.

In the standard interpreted mode everything seems to work ok.  If you have an expression say "a?.b?.c" then if on the object chain b is null you are returned null as I would expect.

The issue occurs when running in mixed mode and it gets compiled after 100 invocations.  In this case when you resolve an object where b is null, it seems that within the spring code a null pointer is thrown and the handled by resetting - but this appears to leave the original compiled class in memory.

If you run a test that repeatedly invokes this routine this you eventually run out of Perm Gen space.

It seems that the null safety checks such as "a?.b?.c" don't seem to be incorporated when used within compiled expressions.

Has anybody seen this previously, have ideas on potential solutions/workarounds?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a bug; I suggestion you open a [JIRA issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR) against the `Core:SpEL` component.

It would be helpful if you attach your test case.